# Dividing Monthly rates to daily records In SQL Server query based on getdate () and accounting for leap years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query here:

```
insert into metrics_rpt
select @start_date, 'PLANNED RATES', sum(qty)
from rates_detail detail 
where detail.id = 1
and detail.year = datepart(yy, @start_date)
and detail.month = datepart (mm, @start_date)
and detail.group_id in (9, 13)
```

This query retrieves a rate sum but instead of retrieving the total sum..

I would like to have a daily value inserted in my metrics_rpt table which
will give a daily value of the rates based off of any month of the year and leap years are
accounted for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Given the name "detail_id", is that the PK of your table? If so, you are retrieving a single row and your sum logically does no addition. Perhaps you should remove that (first) condition from your query? And for the sake of future generations, is it REALLY that much more work to type "month" instead of "mm" (same for "yy")? Don't develop lazy habits.

Comment: id is a column in the rates_detail table , I do not believe it is a pk

Comment: If the tally function is an issue in the query below it could be removed

Answer (score 0):

To project the days forward this query uses a tally table, described [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1).  Given any start date, it splits the @sum_qty by day for the month.

Query

```
declare
  @start_date         date='2020-08-05',
  @sum_qty            int=60000;

select
  dateadd(d, f.N, dt_range.start_dt) daily_dt,
  cast(1/(d_diff.d_diff+1.0)*@sum_qty as decimal(10,2)) daily_qtr
from (select datefromparts(year(@start_date), month(@start_date), 1) start_dt,
             eomonth(@start_date) end_dt) dt_range
     cross apply
     (select datediff(d, dt_range.start_dt, eomonth(dt_range.end_dt)) d_diff) d_diff
     cross apply
     dbo.fnTally(0, d_diff.d_diff) f;
```

Results

```
daily_dt    daily_qtr
2020-08-01  1935.48
2020-08-02  1935.48
2020-08-03  1935.48
2020-08-04  1935.48
2020-08-05  1935.48
2020-08-06  1935.48
2020-08-07  1935.48
2020-08-08  1935.48
2020-08-09  1935.48
2020-08-10  1935.48
2020-08-11  1935.48
2020-08-12  1935.48
2020-08-13  1935.48
2020-08-14  1935.48
2020-08-15  1935.48
2020-08-16  1935.48
2020-08-17  1935.48
2020-08-18  1935.48
2020-08-19  1935.48
2020-08-20  1935.48
2020-08-21  1935.48
2020-08-22  1935.48
2020-08-23  1935.48
2020-08-24  1935.48
2020-08-25  1935.48
2020-08-26  1935.48
2020-08-27  1935.48
2020-08-28  1935.48
2020-08-29  1935.48
2020-08-30  1935.48
2020-08-31  1935.48
```